# AMP(Accelerated Mobile Pages) in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I need to use AMP technology with specific pages in my Drupal website.
I know that I can use AMP module("AMP can be enabled for any node type. At that point, AMP content becomes available on URLs such as ?amp").
But I can't understand what i should do. Should I use two themes, first for AMP pages and second for non amp, or i need only one theme, that would work for all pages(amp and not amp)? Or I can use my non-AMP theme and just add AMP module for some nodes? 
I would like to save my theme and just change some nodes to amp

Answer (score 0):

There is an AMP theme that goes with the AMP module: https://www.drupal.org/project/amptheme.  just install and enable (does not need to be the default theme). The AMP module does the switching for you.

Checkout:

https://www.lullabot.com/articles/how-to-try-out-amp-with-drupal

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an Amptheme available which goes with AMP module as @stevegmag said https://www.drupal.org/project/amptheme. Also, you can create your own custom theme for AMP pages and give that the same look and feel as you have for non-amp pages.